# protobuf-net deserialize base class to inherited class

Tags: serialization, inheritance, protobuf-net, base-class

I have base class which is serialized.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Web2PdfEntity 
{   


        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string CUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to deserialize Web2PdfEntity class to Web2PdfServer which is inherited from Web2PdfEntity.

```
public class Web2PdfServer : Web2PdfEntity
{

public void MyServerMethod {}
public void MyServerMethod2{}
}
```

I have tried to use code below to deserialize class, unfortunately the properties are not set.

```
var web2Pdf = Serializer.Deserialize<Web2PdfServer>("c:\Web2PdfEntity-class-to-serialize-file.bin");
web2Pdf.Title //<- not deserialized
web2Pdf.CURL //<- not deserialized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(heavily revised)

Based on the comments, the scenario presented is:

- there are two types, which *happen* to be subclasses in C#
- in serialization, we just want to flatly swap between them - no inheritance code (i.e. so you can save as `Web2PdfEntity` and load as `Web2PdfServer`, or v.v.)

This is a little different to the *normal* use case, where inherited types expect inheritance during serialization (which changes the data),  and unrelated types are interchangeable as long as the contract fits.

There are a couple of ways of approaching this; one minor issue is that *by default* it doesn't look at inherited properties, to avoid duplication. You *could* re-advertise them, but that is a bit ungainly. Personally, I think I'd be tempted to just tell it what to do during app-startup:

```
var metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Web2PdfServer), false);
metaType.Add(1, "Title").Add(2, "CUrl");
```

Now your existing `Serializer` code will treat `Web2PdfServer` correctly, including the two properties as indicated.

Comment: I can't add [ProtoContract, ProtoInclude(8, typeof(Web2PdfServer))] attribute to  Web2PdfEntity class because Web2PdfEntity will be compiled in class library(separated assembly) which will not include Web2PdfServer class for security reason. Is it possible to solve the problem in other ways?

Comment: @Marc, I have tried to use your code and got error System.InvalidCastException' occurred in protobuf-net.dll while trying to deserialize class var web2Pdf = Serializer.Deserialize<Web2PdfServer>("c:\Web2PdfEntity-class-to-serialize-file.bin");

Comment: @Tomas - the code as written should be fine; do you mean "I used your code minus the attribute"? Re not being able to use the attribs, see update

Comment: I have put attributes as you suggested in your answer and now I get  System.InvalidCastException error using code  
var web2Pdf = Serializer.Deserialize<Web2PdfServer>("c:\Web2PdfEntity-class-to-serialize-file.bin");

Comment: @Tomas - did you *serialize* a `Web2PdfServer`? or did you serialize a `Web2PdfEntity`? If you *serialized* an "entity"... then it ***isn't*** a "server" - it is an "entity". If you just want the data but **don't** want inheritance-based serialization, all you need is `[ProtoContract]` on `Web2PdfServer`

Comment: @Tomas basically, all options are open - I just need to understand how you want it to behave ;p

Comment: @Marc thank you for your patience :) I will try to explain my situation. I have Web2PdfEntity and Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity classes. Web2PdfEntity will be put in one assembly and Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity in another. First assembly will not include reference to Web2PdfServer. I will serialize class Web2PdfEntity and desiarialize it at Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity, do the work with data and Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity will be serialized to file to send data back. Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity class will not include any additional fields, all fields will be inherited from base class..

Comment: ...conclusion. Web2PdfEntity and Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity classes will have the same properties, the difference is that Web2PdfServer: Web2PdfEntity will have additional methods for data manipulation.

Comment: @Tomas OK; I'll rewrite my answer to suit