# protobuf-net Serializing as base class

Tags: inheritance, protobuf-net

I'd like to use protobuf-net to serialize a derived class as its base class.   In other words, I want the serialization process to discard any indication that the type is derived:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Base
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string PublicInfo { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public string SecretInfo { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived()
        {
            PublicInfo = "public info",
            SecretInfo = "secret info"
        };
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(ms, d as Base);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Base deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<Base>(ms);
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialized type: " + deserialized.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialized value: " + deserialized.PublicInfo);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'd like the above program to produce

```
 Deserialized type: Base
 Deserialized value: public info
```

but instead I get an exception about "Type is not expected".

If I add `[ProtoContract]` to `Derived`, the `PublicInfo` field isn't set.  And if I also add `[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Derived))]` to `Base` then the deserialized type is `Derived`, not `Base` as I want.

What am I missing?  Apologies if I've overlooked an answer somewhere else.  I think I'm asking for something like the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505471), though I'd rather not have to explicitly add fields via the `RuntimeTypeModel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your hierarchy isn't too complex you could think about composing your derived type with a serialization member instead of inheriting from it.

```
[ProtoContract] class Generic {
  [ProtoMember(1)] public string PublicInfo { get; set; }
}

class Specialized {
   public Generic Generic { get; set; }
   public string SecretInfo { get; set; }
}
```

There are some parts of your object that are serializable and some parts are serialization unaware. It's not a good idea to mix these in one inheritance hierarchy. Because it doesn't follow the OO concept of specialization. The base class is serializable, the derived class not, however for inheritance the derived class would have to support everything that the base class already supports.

Answer (score 3):

*Most* serializers will choke on that, since they are *designed* to want to allow you to reproduce what you started with. The answer proposed in the related question would *suffice*, but is a bit of a hack and as such *does* require a little voodoo with `RuntimeTypeModel`. In that respect, I quite like the solution in [DonAndre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884695/protobuf-net-serializing-as-base-class/7884881#7884881), which keeps everything pretty clean (and `Specialized` could even be a contract, with `Generic` included and `SecretInfo` omitted).

The only other *thing* to do would be to convince it that your `Derived` is actually a *proxy*. The proxy detection code is not currently customisable at runtime, however it wouldn't be hard to fool it (abusing some knowledge of the implementation), i.e.

```
namespace NHibernate.Proxy {
    internal interface INHibernateProxy {} // pretty spectacularly evil
}
...
class Derived : Base, INHibernateProxy {}
```

now, when it finds it doesn't recognise `Derived` it should check for common *proxy* patterns, find it looks a lot like an NHibernate proxy, and use the base-type. Really horrible and grungy.